# viridis ggplot2 color package won't install , even with dependencies = TRUE

Tags: r, ggplot2, viridis

I boot up a clean instance of R Studio. I don't save my environments and I don't use an Rprofile file. I tried both commands:

```
install.packages("viridis")
install.packages("viridis", dependencies = TRUE)
```

and I get this error:

> - installing *source* package ‘viridis’ ...
>     ** package ‘viridis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** R
>     ** inst
>     ** preparing package for lazy loading Error : object ‘cividis’ is not exported by 'namespace:viridisLite' ERROR: lazy loading failed for
>     package ‘viridis’
> - removing ‘/home/stackinator/Rlibs/viridis’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘viridis’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Try: ```if (!require("devtools")) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("sjmgarnier/viridis")```

Comment: That worked, but why? What happened? Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have added the answer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if (!require("devtools")) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("sjmgarnier/viridis")
```

I am not sure why downloading it from CRAN didn't work, but `devtools::install_github()` downloads the source package from the repository rather than the bundled package that you get from CRAN with `install.packages()`

For more, check out this discussion from `R Packages book`:
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html